# What is the result of an initialization in C++?

Tags: c++, initialization

What is the return value of an initialization? For example:
In the following code;

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int age = 30;          //does this statement return (thus; yield) anything?

    while(int i = 0){      //a similar statement (expression) used here in this condition
        std::cout<<"OK";   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

- What does the statement `int age = 27;` return?
- Does the usual assignment operator meaning apply when there is an initialization, where the left operand of the assignment operator is returned?

The reason why I want to know this is that, when we take a look at the conditional statement above we see a similar initialization of a variable that is used as the condition. I know that whatever value that is returned is converted to the bool type though.

**Note**: I am not trying to compare i to 0 in the condition of the while statement.

Comment: @RPDF OP explicitly mentions that this is not the issue, the question is about something else

Comment: Be careful with terminology. A **function returns** a value, with one or more `return` statements. An **expression has** a value. It doesn't "return" anything.

Comment: In `int age = 30;` the `=`, despite its appearance, is not an assignment. It's an initialization. In C++ that declaration could also be written `int age{30};` with the same meaning. For object types with constructors it's a bit more complicated, but still, that `=` is not an assignment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A declaration statement with an initializer is a just a declaration statement, not an expression. It does not yield a value. You can't do something like `int x = (int n = 42);`.

The `while` loop is something of a special case. You *can* use a declaration as the condition of a `while` loop. According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while),

> If this is a declaration, the initializer is evaluated before each
>   iteration, and if the value of the declared variable converts to
>   false, the loop is exited.

Comment: Okay thanks. But does that means the assignment operator meaning is being used here? And the declaration in this case is yielding an integral type, which is then converted to a bool?

Comment: The declaration has an initialization, not an assignment. That's probably a distinction without a difference for `int`, but may have implications for class types. The declaration is not yielding a value, but a variable that is used to control the loop. The `while` statement evaluates the variable and,  yes, converts the `int` to a `bool`. 0 is falsey, nonzero is truthy.

Comment: Is something like `if (int i = Calculate()) ...` a special case of sorts?  (The predicate part in particular.)  Is that also valid in `C`?

Comment: @Eljay: Yes, [it has the same sort of language for `if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if). But I do not find such language [for C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/while).